# Unresolved symbols when compiling with gcc on OpenSolaris 2008.11

Tags: c, sockets, gcc, netbeans, solaris

When compiling a simple Netbeans C project that uses sockets I get the following output.
I suppose the problem is that gcc is not properly linking sockets.h library.
Need a foolproof method to solve this.

```
Running "/usr/bin/make  -f Makefile CONF=Debug clean" in /export/home/manu/Escritorio/TP-entrega 2/Application_1

/usr/bin/make -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
rm -f -r build/Debug
rm -f dist/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/application_1

Clean successful. Exit value 0.

Running "/usr/bin/make  -f Makefile CONF=Debug" in /export/home/manu/Escritorio/TP-entrega 2/Application_1

/usr/bin/make -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
/usr/bin/make  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/application_1
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/tp2.o.d
gcc   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/tp2.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/tp2.o tp2.c
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86
gcc    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/application_1 build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/tp2.o 

Undefined                        first referenced
 symbol                              in file

bind                                build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/tp2.o

recv                                build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/tp2.o

send                                build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/tp2.o

accept                              build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/tp2.o

listen                              build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/tp2.o

socket                              build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/tp2.o

ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to dist/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/application_1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `dist/Debug/GNU-Solaris-x86/application_1'
Current working directory /export/home/manu/Escritorio/TP-entrega 2/Application_1
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `.build-conf'
Current working directory /export/home/manu/Escritorio/TP-entrega 2/Application_1
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `.build-impl'

Build failed. Exit value 1.
```

Answer (score 11):

You need the appropriate `-l` flag.  I'm looking it up.

Duh.  add `-lsocket`.  Actually, you probably need `-lnsl` too.  See [this man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1466/bind-3socket.html#scrolltoc).

In Netbeans this should be in the [Project Properties](http://cnd.netbeans.org/cnd-tutorial.html#ProjectProperties).

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that the linker is linking the `socket` and `nsl` libraries. At the command line you would add `-lsocket -lnsl` to do so. I don't know netbeans and can't tell you how it works there exactly, but somewhere there should be linker settings where you can add these libraries.